# How to store content to azure file system using java file writer

Tags: java, azure

Currently, I have code for storing and retrieving data from my local file system using file input stream and output stream in java. I have configured the path in the property file. Now I want to achieve the same using azure file system. How can I achieve that? I saw some method using Azure SDK for this, but I want to know any alternative is there to store content into a file in Azure file system without changing my existing code, which means by only changing the property file.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would the java code be any different if the file is on an azure filesystem?

Comment: I think @Jam means Azure Files.  If so, he must use the SDK unless it's mounted in the OS  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to use Azure Storage as same as local file system without using Azure Storage SDK and changing code, just using POSIX File System API in Java.

As I known, per my experience, there are two ways can satisfy your needs.

1. To create an Azure File Share as NFS and mount it with [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows), [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) and [MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-mac).
2. If works on Linux, you also can use Azure Blob Storage to mount a container as a directory to your file system. There is an Azure offical project [azure-storage-fuse](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) on Github which implements a virtual file system adapter for Azure Blob storage via the Linux FUSE kernel module, as the introduction below. It's not completely compatiable with POSIX, but enough for most scenarios.

> **blobfuse**
>
> **About**
>
> blobfuse is an open source project developed to provide a virtual filesystem backed by the Azure Blob storage. It uses the libfuse open source library to communicate with the Linux FUSE kernel module, and implements the filesystem operations using the Azure Storage Blob REST APIs.
>
> Blobfuse is stable, and is supported by Azure Storage given that it is used within its limits documented here. Please submit an issue here for any issues/requests/questions.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Mount a Blob storage container on Linux
> - Basic file system operations such as mkdir, opendir, readdir, rmdir, open, read, create, write, close, unlink, truncate, stat, rename
> - Local cache to improve subsequent access times
> - Parallel download and upload features for fast access to large blobs
> - Allows multiple nodes to mount the same container for read-only scenarios.

The two ways above will create a mount point in local file system to do basic file operations like in a local directory.